# How to implement a git local and private server?

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

I have a small coding business and I need to store all the code inside some Version Control System. I want to use Git, but I prefer to not use it with GitHub/GitLab. I want to install Git on a server from the company, and store over there all the code. That means users must push the commit into the server repo, but I have no idea what's the best infrastructure. Can someone explain briefly or send me any good link? I already made a quick Google search but nothing seems to be OK.

This are the requirements:

- No use of GitHub/GitLab
- One server with all the code.
- Developers will access to it to retrieve changes and push new lines of code.
- Multiple developers should be able to access (not the same file, but same project).

Any help?

Comment: There are various open source git hosting platforms you can install on your own servers, including GitLab.

Comment: You can install Azure DevOps on an in house network. I personally like it for managing work items, browsing code, code reviews via Pull Requests, and pipelines are all generally simple to setup